# Compiling nGinx with modules - No error but no modules

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to compiling `nginx` with `page speed` `brotli` and `openssl`. To do so I used this [script](https://github.com/Angristan/nginx-autoinstall). Despite the fact I'm not running on `Debian 8` but on `Ubuntu 16.04 x64` the installation went well (at least I think)

This is the last line of the `log` of the installation

> make[1](https://github.com/Angristan/nginx-autoinstall): Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/nginx-1.13.1'

#### Problem

When I type `nginx-v` it returns this `nginx version: nginx/1.13.1`

As you can see the modules normally installed are not displayed.

If I do `which nginx` it returns  `/usr/local/sbin/nginx`

#### Questions

What should I do to see the rights modules when entering `nginx-v` ?
Does it mean the installation went wrong even if there was no error ?

Answer (score 0):

Holy Crap ...

`-v` is case sensitive.

`nginx -v` : nginx version: nginx/1.13.1

`nginx -V` :

```
nginx version: nginx/1.13.1
built by gcc 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
configure arguments: --add-module=/home/leo/ngx_brotli --add-module=/home/leo/ngx_pagespeed-1.12.34.2-beta --add-module=/home/leo/nginx_accept_language_module-master --with-openssl=/home/gregory/nginx/openssl-1.1.0e --prefix=/usr/local/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --with-http_v2_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log
```